# stock filter is not adding to layered navigation in magento 2.2.7

Tags: frontend, layered-navigation, product-list, stock, magento2.2.7

Do all the setting but not get the filter in front end for stock

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the page contain both in stock and out of stock products.  The filter will only show if it makes a difference to the result set.

Comment: @DominicXigen yes page contains both in stock and out of stock product, also added the screen shot in the question